Как повторить в Python фильтр "bas relief filter" из Фотошопа?
В Adobe photoshop имеется bas relief filter - он добавляет рельеф к изображению в соответствии с оттенком (более темные участки имеют рельеф выше чем более светлые). Я пытался подобрать подобный фильтр через фильтр Собеля, находя магнитуду, с последующей нормализации изображения, но  безуспешно. Подскажите, с чего вообще можно начать для воспроизведения подобного фильтра в python?
def bas_relief(image):
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
sobel_x = cv2.Sobel(blurred, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)
sobel_y = cv2.Sobel(blurred, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=5)
gradient_magnitude = cv2.magnitude(sobel_x, sobel_y)
norm_gradient = cv2.normalize(gradient_magnitude, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
return norm_gradient


начать можно с приведения вашего кода и примерного изображения прямо в вопросе.

Начать надо с изучения какой нибудь библиотеки для работы с изображениеми, например Pillow.

@чистов_n И cv2 )

@чистов_n я понимаю что opencv и pillow, но мне нужно понять, что конкретно на чем основывается этот фильтр, в математическом плане

начните с того, что создайте тестовые изображения, например, изображение в оттенках серного с черным фоном 0 и одним белым 255 пикселем.  Посмотрите что с ним станет после фильтра.  Если бы это был линейный фильтр, то вы сразу бы в этом случае получили его коэффициенты. Усложните объект, вместо одного пикселя сделайте белый квадрат, проанализируйте результат. И так постепенно, шаг за шагом вы определите что за фильтр используется в фотошопе и как он работает.  Это называется метод черного ящика в исследовании.
